# New Infusionsoft api get all my CRM clients

Tags: php, infusionsoft

So Infusionsoft has changed the PHP SDK and now I am lost. Before I would just get an API key and my Application name to  `conn.cfg.php` like so:

```
$connInfo = array(‘connectionName:applicationName:i:APIKEYGOESHERE:This is
the connection for applicationName.infusionsoft.com’);
?>
```

Now its oAuth and has this to connect:

```
$infusionsoft = new Infusionsoft\Infusionsoft(array(
    'clientId'     => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'clientSecret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    'redirectUri'  => 'http://example.com/',
));
```

What I am confused about is integration. I want to just access clients stuff through my crm api key like before. They are already logged into my custom web app, getting their info is just billing stuff. I dont want them to sign in to my application, then have to sign into infusion soft to get a token. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate access to your Infusionsoft application only once. You can do it yourself, store received access token on your side (in a database or a file) and use it for all following requests to Infusionsoft. You will need to refresh your access token before it expires in 8 hours. It's possible to achieve having a cron job that makes requests to Infusionsoft and refreshes a token regularly.

[Infusionsoft PHP SDK samples](https://github.com/infusionsoft/infusionsoft-php/tree/master/samples) may help you with the basic flow implementation.

Also, currently you still can use API key as before. Though it's unknown for how long time API key access is going to be supported by Infusionsoft.

Comment: Ya after some deeper research this is my game plan but there seems to be a lack of code examples out there. Have you done this before?

Comment: Yes, I've done this before. Link to the PHP SDK samples that show the basic flow was included to the answer.